# How to access Database Actions when ATP is on public endpoint with an access control list (ACL)?

Tags: oracle, oracle-autonomous-db

How can I access Database Actions (or as it was previously called SQL Developer Web) when my ATP instance is on a public endpoint with an access control list (ACL)?

Answer (score 0):

When you have an access control list (ACL) defined, your database allows connections from only those IPs or VCNs that are specified in the ACL. The same is true for Database Actions (or SQL Developer Web) as well. In other words, you need to identify the IP of the connecting client and add it to your ACL in order to be able to connect to Database Actions.